# Nexus OSS 3.0.2-02 initializing but not starting

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I am installing nexus OSS and have it setup according to the docs. I am getting Initializing..... when visiting the /nexus/ context.

I get the below in the nexus.log when the page comes up.

```
-------------------------------------------------

Started Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.0.2-02

-------------------------------------------------
2016-10-18 12:44:40,318-0500 INFO  [qtp1614971838-161] *UNKNOWN org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractValidatingSessionManager - Enabling session validation scheduler...
2016-10-18 12:44:40,345-0500 INFO  [qtp1614971838-161] *UNKNOWN org.sonatype.nexus.security.internal.AnonymousManagerImpl - Using default configuration: AnonymousConfiguration{enabled=true, userId='anonymous', realmName='NexusAuthorizingRealm'}
```

Comment: Did you set up nexus as the context path? If you haven't, try going to just http://localhost:8081 assuming you are running this locally. The default context path in Nexus Repository Manager 3 is / not /nexus (although you can still configure it that way if you'd like).

Comment: So you see the website brought up? But it hangs at "Initializing..."? Can you open your browser's console and see if there is a JavaScript error?

Comment: In NXRM3, "Started" means it started.  What indicator do you have that it's not started?  The log messages you showed are INFO only.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this error was due to the reverse proxy configuration with https because javascript looks by default at the http address (you can see the errors opening the console as it is mentioned in the second comment) and you need to configure it. [Modifying the configuration in apache](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference3/install.html#reverse-proxy) including the line below solves my problem of getting stuck in "Initializing..." in the Nexus 3 GUI:

```
 RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

Comment: (1) this allow applies to nginx
(2) Here is an up to date URL for both Apache and nginx: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation/run-behind-a-reverse-proxy